# Access to the path is denied, when writing to a shared folder

Tags: asp.net, unauthorized, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am using Asp.net and from my code I am trying to write files to a shared folder on another PC in the same domain.

I am getting an exception.

```
UnauthorisedAccessException. Access to the path 'sharedfoldername' is denied.
```

I gave full access permission to everyone on the specified folder with no luck.

Comment: Have you checked the upper level of the folder? If the folder is a child folder, make sure the permission is granted to the parent folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

I should probably, write this in comment but I don't have enough rep yet, I will update my answer as you answer my questions.

Do you access the shared folder from the server/PC where the asp.net application is hosted ? You can create a file with Windows Explorer ?

Does the code is hosted on IIS ?

Comment: Yes the application is hosted on iis.

Comment: No I will not only access the shared folder from the hosted server.

Comment: I think the best pratice here is to create a service user on your domain. Give him access to the shared folder with write permission. And on your IIS create a virtual path that connect to your shared folder with your user. Then it will be easy to access from your application.

Comment: Do you want me to update my answer to show you how to do it ?

Comment: @dbraillon Yes, Please update your answer to show how to do this.